# Spring social ConnectController /connect/facebook gives a 404 error

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I am trying to get the facebook login working with spring social.
**I have created an app on facebook.**

**Dispatcher Servlet**

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**configfured the xmls**

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.cs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Configure a connection repository through which account-to-provider connections will be stored --> 
<beans:bean id="connectionRepository" class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcConnectionRepository">
<beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
<beans:constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
</beans:bean>



<!-- Configure a Facebook service provider -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookServiceProvider">
<beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="564846465216" />
<beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="f4554iojfjh9iu7km54f54pok5ok4" />
<beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="connectionRepository" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors" factory-method="noOpText" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.social.web.connect.ConnectController">
<beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:8080/CitySpanks/" />
</beans:bean>
```

**I am referring this link**
http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/connecting.html

**in my jsp**

```
<a href="<c:url value="connect/facebook" />">Connect to Facebook</a>
```

Anything i am missing ??? I keep getting a 404 error on clicking the above link.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you are at in your project but I think the following may be easy to overlook...

If you look at the sample projects for [spring-social-showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-sec/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/connect) you'll notice that under

```
spring-social-showcase-sec/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/connect
```

exist the following pages:
status.jsp, facebookConnect.jsp, facebookConnected.jsp.

In the sample project when the following (left) is requested it will resolve the .jsp's below (right):

```
"connect/facebook" => Connected => "connect/facebookConnected.jsp"
"connect/facebook" => Not Connected => "connect/facebookConnect.jsp"
"connect"          => "connect/status.jsp"
```

This is documented here: [4.3.1 Displaying a connection page](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#connect-controller-flow-1)

So, to get that example to work in YOUR code you have to create the same directory structure "WEB-INF/views/connect/" with the above .jsp's in it.  Otherwise they will not be found, hence the 404.  I believe this is resolved by the `ConnectController` class, behind the scenes, as described in docs linked above.

---

However, you may want to start off with using their web.xml configuration found in spring-social-samples and once you get the hang of that, go from there.

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: user is getting 404 while trying to access `connect/facebook` mapped to "Connect to Facebook" button

Answer (score 1):

DispatcherServlet is mapped to *.cs, but the link in your JSP is to /connect/facebook (relative to the application root). That URL doesn't end in .cs, so there's no match and DispatcherServlet never gets involved.

Although you can still map DispatcherServlet to any arbitrary URL pattern, the "best practice" since Spring 3.0 is to simply map it to "/", to allow it to respond to a variety of URLs, including those for RESTful APIs.

Of course, that also means that DispatcherServlet will respond to requests for images, style sheets, javascript, and other resources, which is probably not what you want.  and  were created to solve that problem. See the reference documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) and [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) for more details.